# c# disable code region on condition

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, region

So the question is this: I have states in my code. I want to divide them to regions and simply enable or disable them upon some conditions. The code is in a looping Unity function named LateUpdate. I wish to do this to save up on processor time instead of using booleans or enums.
Can I do that? if so, how?
Add. info: I need to do this disabling on runtime. The script is an image sequence player that plays gifs. I have a warm up part then a looping part. I can write it with bools but as I said I need to save on processor time as this will be a mobile game.

some code:

```
void LateUpdate ()
{
    if (warmUp)
    {
        currentImageIndex = Mathf.RoundToInt(Time.time * frameRate);
        currentImageIndex = currentImageIndex % spriteSheet.Length;
        spriteRenderer.sprite = spriteSheet[currentImageIndex];
        warmUp = false;
    }
    if (updateEnabled && !warmUp)
    {
        switch (playMode)
        {
            case PlayMode.order:
                currentImageIndex = Mathf.RoundToInt(Time.time * frameRate);
                currentImageIndex = currentImageIndex % spriteSheet.Length;
                spriteRenderer.sprite = spriteSheet[currentImageIndex];
                break;
            case PlayMode.random:
                updateEnabled = false;
                StartCoroutine(RandomizedPlay());
                break;
        } 
    }

}
```

Comment: What is wrong with putting the regions in `if` blocks that you just set or unset variables as needed to go in to them? There is practically 0 overhead to to a simple `if(_doSection1) { ... }` if `_doSection1` is `false`.

Comment: Sounds like a design-flaw. regions are compiler-statements, you can´t set them during runtime. However why not use simple `if` or loop-statements? Cosnider show some code.

Comment: I don't use regions atm :D don't know how to...
I enclose some code in the question if I can

Comment: see those ifs? it works fine and I know it's not a lot of calculations, but yeah. I have a lot of scripts running in parallel.
the coroutine does its job, it has an infinite loop in it. it plays randomized sprite swaps, not relevant here.

Comment: You should learn how to use [the unity profiler on the mobile device](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Profiler.html), the source of your slowdown (if you are having any) are not from your `if` statements themselves. I would say it is extreemly likely that each of those if checks won't even get above 0.00% of the CPU time during the profiler. YOU ARE LOOKING IN THE WRONG SPOT TO FIX YOUR SLOWNESS, USE A PROFILER AND FIND THE REAL PROBLEM AREA THAT WAY!

Comment: I make sure to check it out. I do not have any slowdown atm. Maybe it is a matter of time. So, is it not possible to just disable a bunch of code?

Comment: Checking  simple boolean won´t slow your app, *if* you have any performance-issues they are definitly caused somewhere else.

Comment: It is possible, ***by using a `if` statement***, that is how you do it.

Comment: The if-statments enablles to execute or not execute a bunch of code determinded by a condition. I think this is exaclty what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple `if` checks like you are currently doing already is the correct way to disable code at runtime that does not always need to run inside a function.

You should learn how to use [the unity profiler on the mobile device](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Profiler.html), the source of your slowdown (if you are having any) are not from your `if` statements themselves.

I would say it is extremely likely that each of those if checks won't even get above 0.00% of the CPU time during the profiler.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I thought always ifing is the noob way and there is some advanced at first :D
Edit: I mean deciding if a bunch of code will NEVER be executed again after it served its purpose. So like it could even be deleted.